# jql query in jira only returning two fields

Tags: jira, jql, python-jira

I am trying to do a query that will return the contents of the summary field in Jira.  Jira doesn't allow the use of "AS" in jql and not finding anything useful in the documentation.

```
            response = jira.search_issues("project=projectName and type=Test and status=Open as fields:summary")
```

If anyone has experience with Jira rest services please advise on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your request to:

```
response = jira.search_issues("project=projectName and type=Test and status=Open", fields="summary")
```

For further information about the `search_issues` function look at: 
http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira.JIRA.search_issues